# Javascript -- Detect Viewable Area of a User's Browser

Tags: javascript

I want to show the user a message showing the viewable area of their browser.  I have the following javascript function for doing this...

```
function main(){
    document.write("The viewable area of your browser is about <b> " + jQuery(window.parent.document).width() + " (width) X " + jQuery(window.parent.document).height() + " (height).</b>");  
}
```

At least one user is reporting that this is giving the wrong values.  For me, this is working properly.

Do you see any weaknesses or limitations in this?

**EDIT: I should have mentioned that this code is in an iframe that pops up over the page that I'm wanting to find the viewable area of.**

Comment: When called after page load, `document.write` will **replace** the current content of the document.

Comment: Won't this give you the dimensions of the page, not the display?  So if the page is 3 pages long you'll get the full height?  Not 100% sure about this.  You say the user says it's wrong... which dimension?  Bigger or smaller than expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `parent.document.body.clientWidth` and `parent.document.body.clientHeight` and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$(window).height()
```

and

```
$(window).width()
```

since

```
jQuery(window.parent.document).width()
```

gives you the height of the document and not of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite simply using:

```
$(window.parent).height();
$(window.parent).width();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. `document.write("The viewable area of your browser is about <b> " + $(window.parent).width() + " (width))`